# Elasticsearch document fields type index automatically changes

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm working on a project containing django, elasticsearch and django-elasticsearch-dsl. I'm collecting a quite large amount of data and saving it to postgres and indexing it to elasticsearch, via django-elasticsearch-dsl.

Im bumping into a problem I dont understant, nor do I have any further hints what happens:

Relevant part of Django's models.py file:

```
class LinkDenorm(BaseModel):
    ...
    link = CharField(null=True, max_length=2710, db_index=True)
    link_expanded = TextField(null=True, db_index=True)
    title = TextField(null=True, db_index=True)
    text = TextField(null=True)
    ...
```

Relevant part of django-elasticsearch-dsl documents.py file:

```
@registry.register_document
class LinkDenorm(Document):
    link_expanded = fields.KeywordField(attr='link_expanded')
   
    class Index:
        name = 'denorms_v10'

    class Django:
        model = models.LinkDenorm

        fields = [
            ...
            'link',
            'title',
            'text',
            ...
        ]
```

After data is successfully indexed, I verify that the index is containing the correct fields:

```
curl -X GET -u <myuser>:<mypasswd> "http://<my-hostname>/denorms_v10/?pretty"

{
  "denorms_v10" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        ...
        "link" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "text" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
        "link_expanded" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After a certain amount of time (sometimes weeks, sometimes days) the index fields are changed. Executing the same CURL lookup as before gives me:

```
curl -X GET -u <myuser>:<mypasswd> "http://<my-hostname>/denorms_v10/?pretty"

{
  "denorms_v10" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        ...
        "link" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "text" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "link_expanded" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After the change happens, the queries fail, since the datatype is not correct. After investigating elasticsearch and django logs, there is nothing that would give a clue what happens with the index.

I'm a bit lost and running out of ideas. Any suggestions are most welcome. Thank you!

Comment: once field types are set they are not changeable, the modified behavior looks like  Elastic's default (schema-less) automatic mapping where it tries to get field types and stores a text and keyword version for character fields

Answer (score 0):

Miha, Your index probably use kind of an ILM without any index template.
Either you query an alias, and aliases under that are changing.
Either a process on your side delete regularly the index (depending on his size or the number of documents in it)
Then when your app do a post again it recreate an index with default Elastic mapping.

Comment: @miha, did my answer helped you? if so, please don't forget to validate it